# highcharts pie donut json - sql

Tags: php, sql, json, highcharts

I'm making a website and I need to place a donut chart, this is the chart that I attempt.

http://jsfiddle.net/pMsAD/1/

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
categories = ['Centro de C.', 'Oficinas C.', 'Canales C.', 'Calle'],
        name = '',
        data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Centro de C.',
                    categories: ['Tv Cable', 'Tv Satelital', 'Internet', 'Telefonia'],
                    data: [13.77, 13.77, 13.77, 13.77],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            }, {
                y: 21.63,
                color: colors[3],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Oficinas C.',
                    categories: ['Tv Cable', 'Tv Satelital', 'Internet', 'Telefonia'],
                    data: [5.40,5.40, 5.40, 5.40],
                    color: colors[1]
                }
            }, {
                y: 11.94,
                color: colors[7],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Canales C.',
                    categories: ['Tv Cable', 'Tv Satelital', 'Internet', 'Telefonia'],
                    data: [2.98, 2.98, 2.98, 2.98],
                    color: colors[2]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7.15,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Calle',
                    categories: ['Tv Cable', 'Tv Satelital', 'Internet', 'Telefonia'],
                    data: [1.78, 1.78, 1.78, 1.78],
                    color: colors[3]

            }, 
            }];
```

That way I can get this data from the database using json.

```
SELECT `cod_ventas`, `cod_per`, `codigo_ori`, `codigo_ser`, `cod_metav`, `cod_sucursal`, `fecha`, `nueva_e`, `recone_e`, `migra_e`, `nueva_s`, `recone_s`, `migra_s`, `nueva`, `recone`, `migra` FROM `ventas`
```

these are the sales data in the table which contains the information I need

Thanks hope I can help

Comment: It looks like you need to place a donut highcharts chart onto your website, but what is the problem?  It looks like the chart works.

Comment: need to bring the chart automatically getting data from the database.